# How to remove or replace vulnerable gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app I developed a couple of years ago with some dependencies in Gemfile.lock that are now security vulnerabilities, but when I run
`bundle update` or `bundle --patch gemname` or `gem install updated-gem`, I continue to get the message:

```
Bundler attempted to update actionview but its version stayed the same
```

First time with gems with vulnerability issue, how do I get them resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do anything in the `Gemfile.lock` file, these are built by rails automatically whenever you install a version of rails in your gem.

First, I would install a gem called `bundle-audit`. Follow the instructions on the documentation on how to use it, this gem will tell you what gems are vulnerable.

Then look at the version of rails you have in your `Gemfile`, not `Gemfile.lock` and compare the version with the version of gem dependencies. If you find that they are the same versions or similar, those a probably the gem dependencies that version of rails came with.

So what you do is change your version of rails to the next recommended version.

Do a `bundle update`, this will rebuild your gem dependencies in your `Gemfile.lock` from scratch and then you should be golden. You can verify that by doing another `bundle-audit check` command. If it says no vulnerabilities found or something like that, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

this is more a manual way of removing the vulnerable gems. You may have to put the right gem version which do not have the security vulnerability in the

`Gemfile`

like this, assuming this version has no security vulnerability

`gem 'rails',        '5.1.2'`

rename or remove the `Gemfile.lock`

`mv Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock_`

and run

`bundle update`

this is more a manual way of removing the vulnerable gems. You may have to put the right gem version which do not have the security vulnerability in the `Gemfile` like this `gem 'rails',        '5.1.2'` and perform `bundle update`

Comment: Raga, all this did was create another ```Gemfile.lock``` with the same gems! How do I get the same version gems twice?!

Comment: this is more a manual way of removing the vulnerable gems. You may have to put the right gem version which do not have the security vulnerability in the `Gemfile` like this `gem 'rails',        '5.1.2'` and perform `bundle update`